# Android EditText validation

Tags: java, android, validation, if-statement, android-edittext

I have two `EditText` like **editText1** and **editText2**.

I am taking input from `EditText` to **name1** and **name2**.

Now I want to validate that the `EditText` are not empty before clicking on ok button.

For this I used:

```
if(editText1==NULL && editText2==NULL) {
    textView.setText("please enter Names");
} else {
    other code;
}
```

But its not validating, and with empty `EditText` it is showing result on clicking ok button.

I have also tried in this way:

```
if(name1==NULL && name2==NULL) {
    textView.setText("please enter Names");
} else {
    other code;
}
```

What to do?

Comment: simple and best solution to use `TextUtils.isEmpty(editText1.getText())`. read more about http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isEmpty(java.lang.CharSequence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use:

```
 if(name1.compareTo("") == 0 || name2.compareTo("") == 0) {
     // Your piece of code for example
     Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ENTER NAMES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);  
     toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
     toast.show();
 } else {
     // Your code  
 }
```

This will work definitely for sure.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
if(editText1.getText().toString().trim().equals("") 
    && editText2.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
{
    textView.setText("Please enter Names");
}
else
{
    // other code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this `name1.equals("")` in place of `name1==NULL`

```
if(name1.equals("") && name2.equals(""))
{
  textView.setText("please enter Names");
 }
  else
 {
    other code;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(name1.compareTo("") == 0 || name2.compareTo("") == 0)
{
    // Your piece of code for example
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(editText1.getText().toString().length() > 0 && editText2.getText().toString().length() > 0)
{
    textView.setText("Please enter Names");
}
else
{
    // Other code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
if(name.compareTo("") == 0 || name.compareTo(null) == 0) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works very well for me, try this

```
if(editText1.getText().toString().length == 0 && editText2.getText().toString().length == 0)

{
    textView.setText("Please enter names");
}
else
{
    //some other actions to perform
}
```