# CalculateButton in BMI calculator

Tags: android

it's me again... I want to ask how to make my "button" (calculateButton) not to function if the user won't input their weight & height... or the user don't input their weight or their height...  Hope you can help me... thanks..

Here is the code for my calculateButton:

```
   public void calculateClickHandler(View view) {

    if (view.getId() == R.id.calculateButton) {

                }

        EditText weightText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weightT);
        EditText heightText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.heightT);
        TextView resultText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultLabel);
        TextView categoryText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.categoryLabel);
        rGroup  = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rGroup);


    int weight = (int)  Float.parseFloat(weightText.getText().toString());
    int height = (int) Float.parseFloat(heightText.getText().toString());
        int bmiValue = calculateBMI(weight, height);

    String bmiInterpretation = interpretBMI(bmiValue);

    resultText.setText("Your BMI is:" + " " + bmiValue + " " + "and you're");
        categoryText.setText(bmiInterpretation + ".");}
```

Comment: Check out the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html).

Answer (score 1):

You need to insert "validations" in your code. Basically checking the value of the `string` in your `EditText` before performing any operation.

Something like:

```
    rGroup  = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rGroup);

if( !weightText.getText().toString.equals(" ")){
    int weight = (int)  Float.parseFloat(weightText.getText().toString());
    int height = (int) Float.parseFloat(heightText.getText().toString());
        int bmiValue = calculateBMI(weight, height);
    }
```

Refer:
[Android, Validate an empty EditText field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184128/android-validate-an-empty-edittext-field)
https://sites.google.com/site/khetiyachintan/sample-example/edit-text-validation-example
[Android EditText validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050412/android-edittext-validation)

Comment: i got error in ".toString!=null" ... it say's toString cannot be resolved or it is not a field...

Comment: @deloy that is where you place the code, just gave you an idea, pls study a bit about the validations and related code(s) from other links too